# Is it possible to implement a trait for a generic type in Rust?

Tags: rust, traits

The code snippet below comes from substrate https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/client/state-db/src/lib.rs.

What does it do? How can you implement a trait `Hash` for a generic type `T`? Commenting out the `impl <...>` and the compiler complains "the trait `Hash` is not implemented for `Vec<u8>`", but how that empty piece of code (`impl<...>`) implements `Hash` for `Vec<u8>`?

```
pub trait Hash:
    Send
    + Sync
    + Sized
    + Eq
    + PartialEq
    + Clone
    + Default
    + fmt::Debug
    + Codec
    + std::hash::Hash
    + 'static
{
}
impl<
        T: Send
            + Sync
            + Sized
            + Eq
            + PartialEq
            + Clone
            + Default
            + fmt::Debug
            + Codec
            + std::hash::Hash
            + 'static,
    > Hash for T
{
}
```

Comment: What is the question? `Vec<u8>` implements all traits in the bounds, so this `impl` impls `Hash` for it.

Comment: Why do we need `impl<...> Hash for T` then if `Vec<u8>` already implements all the traits (somewhere else)?

Comment: Because otherwise it won't be implementing `Hash`? And you either wouldn't be able to hang behaviour off of that, or you would have to repeat all the trait bounds every time you want to depend on them?

Comment: Now to be fair this is a bit of a hacky use case, and will likely eventually be mostly obviated by the stabilisation of [trait aliases](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/41517). But currently trait aliases are not stable, so...

Answer (score 3):

> What does it do? How can you implement a trait Hash for a generic type T?

Like that? It's called a "blanket implementation", and implements the trait for all types (usually with specific generic bounds, but not necessarily).

> how that empty piece of code (impl<...>) implements Hash for Vec?

Hash is a *marker trait*, it doesn't contain anything, it just opts into some sort of capability (the most well known marker traits in Rust are `Sized`, `Send`, and `Sync`). So to implement it you just needs to say `impl Hash for Type`.

But you could certainly do that with a non-marker trait as well, as long as you only used contents from the traits you defined as trait bounds. For instance [the `FutureExt` trait is blanket-implemented on all types which implement `Future` and adds a bunch of utility methods](https://docs.rs/futures-util/0.3.21/src/futures_util/future/future/mod.rs.html#119). That's a common pattern, with [a conventional RFC](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/0445-extension-trait-conventions.html) explaining the pattern and why you'd want to apply it.

Comment: I'd posit that `Copy` might be the most-known marker trait in Rust. ;) (Though I guess you could argue it's not a pure marker trait since it also requires `Clone`.)

Comment: @cdhowie good point, I guess interaction with it is so universal I didn't even think about it.

Answer (score 3):

Rust allows you to implement *your* traits for any types, including other people's types. To help with this Rust allows implementing traits for (partially) generic types, as long as it's your trait (see [orphan rules](https://rust-lang.github.io/chalk/book/clauses/coherence.html)).

What might be confusing in this context is that `Hash` also exists as `std::hash::Hash`. But these two are not the same trait, despite having the same name. It would be easier to understand if we renamed it to `Foo`, and focused on, say, `PartialEq + Eq`.

```rust
// We make a new trait named Foo and say that any type implementing Foo
// must also implement PartialEq and Eq.
trait Foo : PartialEq + Eq { }

// For any type implementing PartialEq and Eq, implement Foo for that type.
// This is allowed because we also created Foo.
impl<T: PartialEq + Eq> impl Foo for T { }
```

This
'trick' is often used to combine many traits (like in your `Hash` example) into a single name (called a marker trait). But it's not limited to that, for example you could make the following trait:

```rust
trait Reset: Default {
    fn reset(&mut self);
}

impl<T: Default> Reset for T {
    fn reset(&mut self) {
        *self = Self::default();
    }
}
```

Now any type that implements `Default` will have a `reset()` method that returns it to the default state thanks to our generic implementation (also called a blanket implementation), as long as you have the `Reset` trait in scope.

Answer (score 0):

`Hash` is an empty trait with no methods. It inherits a lot of other traits so any `struct` you `impl` it for needs to `impl` all the traits it inherits from.

So if you have a generic  `<T : Trait1 + Trait2 +...>` the compiler knows that type `T` satisfies all the trait dependencies for `trait Hash`

So what this code does is impl Hash for any T that implements all the inherited traits